# Javascript add row to HTML table with text and onClick

Tags: javascript, html

i am adding a new table row in javascript:

```
var i=1;
function addRow(seq, nominalcode, description, quantity, unitprice) {
    seq = seq || '';
    nominalcode = nominalcode || '';
    description = description || '';
    quantity = quantity || '';
    unitprice = unitprice || '';

    var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length - 4;
    //var iteration = lastRow - 1;
    var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

    row.id = 'item_row_' + i;

    var Cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    var elItemSequence = document.createElement('input');
    elItemSequence.type = 'hidden';
    elItemSequence.name = 'item_sequence' + i;
    elItemSequence.id = 'item_sequence' + i;
    elItemSequence.value = seq;
    Cell0.appendChild(elItemSequence);

    var elNominalcode = document.createElement('input');
    elNominalcode.type = 'textarea';
    elNominalcode.className = 'form-control';
    elNominalcode.name = 'nominal_code' + i;
    elNominalcode.id = 'nominal_code' + i;
    elNominalcode.placeholder = 'Nominal Code';
    elNominalcode.value = nominalcode;
    Cell0.appendChild(elNominalcode);

    var Cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var elDescription = document.createElement('textarea');
    elDescription.type = 'textarea';
    elDescription.className = 'form-control';
    elDescription.name = 'description' + i;
    elDescription.id = 'description' + i;
    elDescription.placeholder = 'Description';
    elDescription.value = description;
    elDescription.cols = 40;
    elDescription.rows = 2;
    Cell1.appendChild(elDescription);

    var Cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    var elQuantity = document.createElement('input');
    elQuantity.type = 'text';
    elQuantity.className = 'form-control';
    elQuantity.name = 'quantity' + i;
    elQuantity.id = 'quantity' + i;
    elQuantity.placeholder = 'Quantity';
    elQuantity.value = quantity;
    elQuantity.value = quantity;
    Cell2 .appendChild(elQuantity);

    var Cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
    var elUnitPrice = document.createElement('input');
    elUnitPrice.type = 'text';
    elUnitPrice.className = 'form-control';
    elUnitPrice.name = 'unitprice' + i;
    elUnitPrice.id = 'unitprice' + i;
    elUnitPrice.placeholder = 'Price';
    elUnitPrice.value = unitprice;
    Cell3.appendChild(elUnitPrice);

    var Cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
    var elDelete = document.createElement('a');
    elDelete.href = '#';
    elDelete.onclick = function(){ DeleteInvoiceLine(seq, i) };
    elDelete.text = 'Delete' + i;
    Cell4.appendChild(elDelete);

    i++;
    document.getElementById('numrows').value = (i-1);
    //alert(i);
}
```

in the above code there is an `onClick` action which calls a function

but everytime the row is added its running the function, how can i make it only call the function on click of the `a` anchor

my function is:

```
function DeleteInvoiceLine(seq, row_num) {
    alert(seq + '/' + row_num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try anonymous function

`elDelete.onclick = function(){ DeleteInvoiceLine(seq) };`

Comment: that seems to work, ive also added another arguement to my function so now its `function DeleteInvoiceLine(seq, row_num) {` so when calling it i have added `DeleteInvoiceLine(seq, i)` but `i` is the same number in the function for all rows however if i view the value of `i` its the correct row number

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code.
1. `elDelete.onclick=...` not `onClick`
2. As you note `DeleteInvoiceLine(seq)` run at the moment the element created.
This is because you assign **result** of the function, not **function** to `onclick` event.
3. (not asked yet) What is `sec` variable? I suspect something like `for(var sec=0;sec<N;sec++)` and your code is inside the loop. This will not work (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).
4. `elDelete.onclick = function(){ DeleteInvoiceLine(seq) };` doesn't work because `sec` is out of scope at the moment of click.
Some fixes.

```
var i = 0;
//...
for(var sec=0;sec<N;sec++){
//your code
elDelete.onclick = DeleteInvoiceLine(seq, i);//I keep it with purpose
//your code
}
//...
i++;
//The key moment
function DeleteInvoiceLine(seq, row_num){
   //sec comes here from the loop
   return function(){//note (); (sec) would kill all construction
                     //and in this context would be **event {type:'click'}
      $.ajax(
        //your code which uses **sec** and/or **row_num**
        //this time sec and row_num are available from parent scope
      );//$.ajax
   }//return function
}//function DeleteInvoiceLine
```

Comment: check my update - its working fine calling the function now and the `seq` variable is correct. its just the `i` variable in the function is not correct. in my `alert` inside the function, the `row_num` variable is the last row for every other row but where i have put it here: `elDelete.text = 'Delete' + i;` its the correct row number

Comment: How do you call `addRow(seq, nominalcode, description, quantity, unitprice)` ? And how many rows you add?

Comment: It's calling this on page load inside a php loop so for however many rows it's selecting from a table

Comment: And what is `alert(sec+'/'+row_num)`?

Comment: Sec is nothing but seq is the sequence from the database and row_num is supposed to be the value of i but it's not

Comment: seq is the sequence column of the row from the database and row_num is returning the last row number for all rows. For example if there are 5 rows it returns 5 and if there are 8 rows or returns 8. But row 1 should return 1, row 2 should return 2 and so on for each row

Comment: "but it's not". This is exactly what I expect.

Comment: Read my answer. Your `sec` and `i` are out of scope at the moment you click. `i` is always the number of rows.

Comment: Can you see my addrow function, in there I add an id to each tr added which includes the i variable...

Comment: I saw your code. This is why I wrote the answer. Just read it again.

Comment: The i I am adding to each row is correct but it's not correct in the function.  I updated my question with more code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116274/discussion-between-alex-kudryashev-and-charlie).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
elDelete.setAttribute("onclick", "DeleteInvoiceLine("+ seq +","+ i +")");
....
```